# Javascript remove classes from all elements on hover

Tags: javascript

I am grabbing all `item` elements using `querySelectorAll` and then attempting to remove the `primary` class..

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    
    var cells = document.querySelectorAll(".item");
    
    for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {

        cells[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
            this.classList.remove("primary");
        });

    }

});
```

This is working but instead of removing the `primary` class from the hovered element I want it to remove it from all of the `item` elements when one is hovered.

Anyone have an example?

Comment: And the problem is? All you need is already in your script.

Comment: _“I want it to remove it from all of the item elements when one is hovered”_ - well then you need to loop over `cells` again, and remove the class from each one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you delegate to the common container instead of adding an event listener to each item

Then you can loop over all the container items when you moused over one of them instead of repeating the loop

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const container = document.getElementById("container"); // or whatever selector on the item container
  container.addEventListener("mouseover", function(e) {
    const tgt = e.target;
    if (tgt.classList.contains("primary")) {
      container.querySelectorAll(".item").forEach(item => item.classList.remove("primary"));
    }
  });
});
```